# @PreAuthorization comparison against a custom JWT attribute

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to secure a Spring Boot 2.2.2 application using Keycloak 8.0.1.

The JWT token looks like this (please note the extra customer_id field):

```
{ user: {
    authorities: [...],
    details: {
      roles: [...],
      principal: {
        name: "first",
        keycloakSecurityContext: {
          token: {
            ...,
            customer_id: "first",
            ...
          } } } } } }
```

I'd like to protect this entry point:

```
// eg.: http://localhost:9000/customers/first
@GetMapping(@Path path = "/customers/{customerId}")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(????.customer_id == #customerId)
public Object customerEntryPoint(@PathVariable String customerId) {
    ...
}
```

What would be a suitable @PreAuthorization expression, so I compare 'customer_id' field in token to the provided customerId parameter?

Answer (score 0):

After 2 hours, I manage to find a solution that's not too elegant:

```
@PreAuthorize("principal.keycloakSecurityContext.token.getOtherClaims().get('customer_id')==#customerId")
```

If somebody can provide a more elegant solution, I'll appreciate it.